# What are JDT files? How do you open JDT files?

Tags: file-format

What are JDT files? How do you open JDT files?

Comment: What OS? 15chars

Comment: Do you have any details as to what they're from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick Google search brings:

> File Type: **Capture Classic Filler -
>   Accelio JetForm**
>   Filename: Capture
>   Classic Filler - Accelio JetForm
>   Extension JDT
>   Class: **XML**
>
> The JDT file type is primarily
>   associated with 'Capture Classic Filler' by
>   Accelio. JetForm Corp became Accelio
>   in September 2001. After that, in April 2002, [Adobe Systems acquired Accelio](http://www.adobe.com/support/products/enterprise/support_productnames.html).

You need "Accelio® Capture Classic Filler" software to open files with JDT extension.

Answer (score 1):

JDT is Jetform program, changed name in 2001 to Accelio, and was bought out by Adobe in 2002. Still working on finding something (free) that will open them, but only been looking for a few minutes.